# Updating an entity via thymeleaf and spring mvc

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am using spring mvc, thymeleaf and basic html to register a user, after registering the user is prompted to enter his position with a form, how can i pass the registered users id and the selected "position" to the spring controller.

Here is my html:

```
 Logged in
<h4>Player: <h4 th:text="${username}" /> </h4>

<h4>ID:<h4 th:text="${id}" /> </h4>

  <a style="color:blue" th:href="@{/home}">HomeScreen!</a> 




</center>   

<center>
```

```
<h4>Update Position</h4>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/updatePlayer}" th:object="${player}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Preferred Position:</td>

            <td><select name="Position" th:field="*{position}" >
                <option value="TightHead">TightHead (1)</option>
                <option value="Hooker">Hooker (2)</option>
                <option value="LooseHead">LooseHead (3)</option>
                <option value="SecondRow">Second Row (4/5)</option>
                <option value="BlindSideFlanker">Blindside Flanker(6)</option>
                <option value="OpenSideFlanker">Openside Flanker(7)</option>
                <option value="Eight">Eight(8)</option>
                <option value="ScrumHalf">ScrumHalf(9)</option>
                <option value="OutHalf">OutHalf(10)</option>
                <option value="LeftWing">Left Wing(11)</option>
                <option value="InsideCentre">Inside Centre (12)</option>
                <option value="OutsideCentre">Outside Centre (13)</option>
                <option value="RightWing">Right Wing (14)</option>
                <option value="FullBack">Fullback (15)</option>

            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>

</td>

<br />
          <a style="color:blue" th:href="@{/home}">HomeScreen!</a>

</center>
```

As you can see from this I am able to display the newly registered users id by passing it through the controller.
In the position form I am passing th:object = player when I should be passing the variable "position" but unsure how.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePlayer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updatePlayer(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @RequestParam("position") String position) {

        //

        UserLogin updateUser = userRepository.findOne(id);
        updateUser.setPosition(position);

        userRepository.save(updateUser);
          //need to figure out how to pass variable from update form to here and set the "user"s position to the selected value

        return "welcome";

    }
```

I am requesting the variables: id, position from the html page using @ParamRequest but am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'position' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:401) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:328) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:294) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `th:field=*{some user field}"` is for binding your input with a **property in the form-backing bean**, like if you were injecting `@ModelAttribute User user` in controller.

However, your controller is trying to inject `Long id` and `String position`, so in your form you need to have two `th:name` with user id and selected position accordingly.

Comment: I changed th:field="*{position}" to th:name="*{position}" and did the same for id, after doing this I got this error: There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'position' is not present

Comment: use `th:name="position"` to name parameter, and `th:value="${position}"` to extract value

Answer (score 1):

The first problem comes from you controlor.
As you want to handle the form from a POST request, the form content will not be send by url.
The best wait could be to create a simple object you call something like playerPositionForm, initialize,and add it to the model in your GET controllor.

```
 public String display(Model model) {
    final PlayerPositionFormregleForm playerPositionForm = new playerPositionForm();

    model.addAttribute("playerPositionForm ", playerPositionForm ); return "view";
```

In your HTML you have to bind it to the form. Just replace

```
th:object="${player}"
```

by

```
th:object="${playerPositionForm }"
```

And finally in your POST method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePlayer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updatePlayer(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @ModelAttribute("playerPositionForm ") PlayerPositionFormregleForm,Model model playerPositionForm ) {
```